# PyQt5. Диалоговое окно. Как убрать кнопку ОК?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyside2, qmessagebox

Как убрать кнопку **`ОК`** или переименовать её? 
Она появляется по умолчанию.

```
def FileNotSave(self): 
        self.dlg = QMessageBox()
        self.dlg.show()
        self.dlg.yes = 
          self.dlg.addButton("Да",QMessageBox.AcceptRole)
        self.dlg.no = 
          self.dlg.addButton("Нет",QMessageBox.AcceptRole)
        self.dlg.canel = 
          self.dlg.addButton("Назад",QMessageBox.RejectRole)
        self.dlg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Information)
        self.dlg.setWindowTitle("Сохранение")
        self.dlg.setInformativeText("Сохранить текущий документ?")
        self.dlg.exec()
        if self.dlg.clickedButton() == self.dlg.yes:
            if self.path == None:
                #self.SaveWhat()
                pass
            else:
                #self.Save()
                pass
            return 1
        elif self.dlg.clickedButton() == self.dlg.no:
            return 1
        else:
            return 0
```

Comment: а что ваш предыдущий вопрос решен или нет ?

Comment: да вопрос решён

Comment: а вам мой ответ был чем-то полезен или нет?

Comment: @ТимонЯблоков надо благодарить людей за помощь, отмечать ответ галочкой.

Comment: @Bulson - да я знаю но ответ S. Nick к сожалению не был мне полезен я имел ввиду другое

Comment: Ну, тогда ОК...

Comment: все может быть, в таком случае я вам предлагаю опубликовать свой ответ и отметить его как правильный. И тогда будем считать , что вопрос закрыт.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48095573/how-to-disable-ok-button-in-qinputdialog-if-nothing-is-typed

Comment: @S. Nick. Для решения мне не потребовался какой либо код.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я отметил для вас строки, которые я поменял.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Winform(QWidget):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(Winform,self).__init__(parent)
        self.btn = QPushButton("Вызвать FileNotSave", self)
        self.btn.setGeometry(QRect(100, 100, 75, 23))
        self.btn.adjustSize()                                            
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.FileNotSave)        

    def FileNotSave(self): 
        self.dlg = QMessageBox()
#        self.dlg.show()                                           # это ваш OK 
#            self.dlg.yes = 
        self.dlg.addButton("Да", QMessageBox.AcceptRole)
#            self.dlg.no = 
        self.dlg.addButton("Нет", QMessageBox.AcceptRole)
#            self.dlg.canel = 
        self.dlg.addButton("Назад",QMessageBox.RejectRole)
        self.dlg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Information)
        self.dlg.setWindowTitle("Сохранение")
        self.dlg.setInformativeText("Сохранить текущий документ?")
        bttn = self.dlg.exec()

#        if self.dlg.clickedButton() == self.dlg.yes:
        if self.dlg.clickedButton().text() == "Да":               # + text()
            print("Да")
            '''
            if self.path == None:
                #self.SaveWhat()
                pass
            else:
                #self.Save()
                pass
            '''
            return 1

        elif self.dlg.clickedButton().text() == "Нет":              # + text()
            print("Нет")
            return 1
        else:
            print("Назад")
            return 0        


if __name__ == "__main__":  
    app = QApplication(sys.argv) 
    form = Winform()
    form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]